# When I am using relative path in install4j and then use getCanonicalPath() method on that relative path it return wrong absolute path?

Tags: java, installation, install4j

Like if am using data/conf/filename.txt as relative path whose correct absolute path is C:/username/data/conf but instead of that install4j return C:/Windows/temp/e4j906.tem_dir477546661/data/conf/filename.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relative path is resolved relative to the working directory. For installers generated by install4j, the working directory is in a temporary directory.

You have to construct the absolute directory yourself. If it is in the user home directory:

```
new File(System.getProperty("user.home", "data/conf/filename.txt"))
```

If it is in the installation directory, the context has a method for resolving files:

```
context.getDestinationFile("data/conf/filename.txt")
```